# Java KeyListener is giving me "Unknown keyCode:0x0"

Tags: java, event-handling

```
class KeyDemoFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
    String line1;
    KeyDemoFrame()
    {

        setTitle("hello");
        setSize(200,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        line1 = e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getKeyCode());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

When I press any key, I get "0" for the first message dialog and "Unknown keyCode:0x0" for the second one.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Java Documentation for a [KeyEvent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html):

> [getKeyCode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode%28%29)
>   Returns: the integer code for an actual key on the keyboard. (For KEY_TYPED events, the keyCode is VK_UNDEFINED.)

You are using a keyTyped event, thus the value being returned is VK_UNDEFIED.

You can, however, just use the following to get the character that was typed:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getKeyChar());
```

Comment: Pretty sure you added the e.getKeyChar() to your answer (via edit) after my answer was submitted, poor form.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have non-US layout as a default one. Java doesn't like it and generates events with invalid keycodes. As a countermeasure you can assign US a primary layout.

Comment: My problem was appeared in ubuntu 13.04 and IntellijIDEA 12.10. I was not able to use Keys combination, setting the keyboard layout English to be the default fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use e.getKeyChar()

Comment: returns some weird square sign, not the actual key. not helping.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get `KeyCode` in `KeyPressed` event and then you can use it in `KeyTyped`, of course the variable you will use have to be declared outside these two events.

Answer (score 0):

You also need this to ctach the event, I think:

```
/**
     * Notification that an event has occured in the AWT event
     * system
     * 
     * @param e Details of the Event
     */
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e) {
        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
            keyPressed((KeyEvent) e);
        }
        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
            keyReleased((KeyEvent) e);
        }
        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
            keyTyped((KeyEvent) e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @w4j3d: By accepting an answer (presumably the best answer) by clicking the check mark below at the top left corner of the answer (below the big number).

Comment: He does not need to "catch the event". He is receiving events properly.

Answer (score 0):

You may get three types of events: `KEY_PRESSED`, `KEY_RELEASED`, and `KEY_TYPED` events. The first two are associated to the action of pressing and releasing keys on the keyboard (which may or may not result in a character being typed), while the third one is associated with character input:

- For `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` events:

  - `e.getKeyCode()` returns a valid key code
  - `e.getKeyChar()` returns `CHAR_UNDEFINED`
- For `KEY_TYPED` events:

  - `e.getKeyChar()` returns a valid Unicode char
  - `e.getKeyCode()` returns `VK_UNDEFINED`

Your code is listening to `KEY_TYPED` events, but then using `e.getKeyCode()` which is only valid for `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` events.